# Привязка к процессу

Tags: python

Есть ли такая возможность чтоб привязать скрипт к отдельному процессу?
В идеале чтоб он выполнялся в этом окне, не затрагивая остальные
Делаю что то на подобие кликера
Гугол не дал внятной инфы

Comment: Можно через `Process` запустить код в отдельном процессе (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) или через subprocess (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) запустить другую программу (или скрипт) и взаимодействовать с нею через консоль

Comment: Блин, только щас понял что не правильно сформулировал
Мой скрипт и так будет запускаться через exe, мне нужно что данный скрипт был привязан к конкретной программе, собственно для которой он и делается. Чтоб он именно там работал, не затрагивая остальные окна

Comment: Добавьте контекста в вопрос пока непонятно что именно делает скрипт и какие проблемы возникли

Comment: В общем, скрипт, он же кликер будет делать определенные действия в другой программе, клики он будет делать по координатам на основе своего алгоритма, мне нужно чтоб скрипт делал клики в том окне что я ему скажу и больше нигде

Comment: Думаю, без win api не обойтись, например чтобы знать окно, его заголовок и его процесс